# How to play multiple audio files in a row with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have 5 songs in my app that I would like to play one after the other with AVAudioPlayer.

Are there any examples of this? How can I accomplish this?

Any example code would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's very hard to find any information about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every song you want to make make a single `AVPlayer`.

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pathToYourFile];`

`AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];`


`[audioPlayer play];`

You can get a Notification when the player ends. Check `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` when setting up the player:

```
  audioPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone; 

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                               name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                             object:[audioPlayer currentItem]];
```

this will prevent the player to pause at the end.

in the notification:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // start your next song here
}
```

You can start your next song as soon as you get a notification that the current playing song is done. Maintain some counter which is persistent across selector calls. That way using `counter % [songs count]` will give you an infinite looping playlist :)

Don't forget un unregister the notification when releasing the player.

Comment: what do i put in playerItemDidReachEnd? audioPlayer2 play? what if I have 5 songs?

Comment: yeah you could do that. The code i put above is theoretical. It could would but not guaranteed. But the idea seems workable...

Answer (score 15):

AVQueuePlayer work for this situation.

[AVQueuePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a subclass of AVPlayer you use to play a number of items in sequence.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of AVAudioPlayer you can use AVQueuePlayer which suits this use case better as suggested by Ken.
Here is a bit of code you can use:

```
@interface AVSound : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVQueuePlayer* queuePlayer;

- (void)addToPlaylist:(NSString*)pathForResource ofType:(NSString*)ofType;
- (void)playQueue;

@end

@implementation AVSound
- (void)addToPlaylist:(NSString*)pathForResource ofType:(NSString*)ofType
{
    // Path to the audio file
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathForResource ofType:ofType];

    // If we can access the file...
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {

        AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

        if (_queuePlayer == nil) {
            _queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
        }else{
            [_queuePlayer insertItem:item afterItem:nil];
        }
    }

}


- (void)playQueue
{
    [_queuePlayer play];
}
@end
```

Then to use it:
In your interface file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSound *pageSound;
```

In your implementation file:

```
- (void)addAudio:(Book*)book pageNum:(int)pageNum
{

    NSString *soundFileEven = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", pageNum-1];
    NSString *soundPathEven = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", book.productId,     soundFileEven];
    NSString *soundFileOdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", pageNum];
    NSString *soundPathOdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", book.productId, soundFileOdd];

    if (_pageSound == nil) {
        _pageSound = [[AVSound alloc]init];
        _pageSound.player.volume = 0.5;
    }

    [_pageSound clearQueue];

    [_pageSound addToPlaylist:soundPathEven ofType:@"mp3"];
    [_pageSound addToPlaylist:soundPathOdd ofType:@"mp3"];
    [_pageSound playQueue];
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AVAudioPlayer can only play one file. To play two files, you have to kill the first instance of the AVAudioPlayer and recreate it a second time (it can be initiated using `- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError **)outError`). The problem with this approach is that there is a slight delay between when the first file finishes playing and when the second file starts playing. If you want to get rid of this delay you have to dig into [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/) and come up with a much more complex solution.

Comment: i think there is a way. check out my answer. `AVPlayer` has a notification selector which tells us when a currently playing song is over. That way we can play our next song as soon as current is done. That could work.

Comment: I actually made a radio app for the iPhone and iPad. I know as of iOS 4.2 there was still a delay when trying to play two files in a row using AVAudioPlayer. I even tried to prep a separate AVAudioPlayer using the `prepareToPlay` method and have the second one start playing as soon as the first one was done, but there was still a slight delay. If you don't mind a slight delay between the sounds it's no big deal, but if you want completely continuous playback between the two files I don't think AVAudioPlayer is the way to go.

Comment: cant imagine having a noticeable gap when trying to use notification unless the audio file itself has white noise or some blank noise at the end. That way `AVAudioPlayer` would still play but the user thinks there is gap. Still curious to know why this is so...

Comment: the gap comes from the AVAudioPlayer prepping to play the audio file