# how to play songs sequencial and shuffeled in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play songs. I have an array of MPMediaItem. I want sequential and shuffled on button click.

**My code is:**

```
 AVAudioPlayer *player2;
 MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:i];
 NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
[player2 release];
player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[player2 play];
```

please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677897/how-do-i-play-multiple-files-in-avaudioplayer/15678021#15678021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are playing the songs present in your iPod library then you can make use of `MPMusicPlayerController`, this class contains bunch of property to change the states like `shuffleMode` or `repeatMode`.

If you are using `AVAudioPlayer` add a receiver for notification `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` and inside the observer query your array `arrAnand` to fetch the random mediaItem

Hope this helps you.

**Edit :**

Inside `itemDidFinishPlaying`

```
-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying 
{
    MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:i]; 
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    if(player2)
    {
          [player2 release];
          player2 = nil;
    }
    player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil]; 
    [player2 play];
}
```

**Note :** where i is any random number (should be less than the [arrAnand count]).

Comment: sir i am new in iPhone..can YOU elaborate?

Comment: ` MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
 AVPlayer* player = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem] autorelease];
[player play];}
-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying {
    
    // Will be called when AVPlayer finishes playing playerItem
}`

Comment: ok, inside `-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying` get the media item using MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:i];
NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];    where i is any random number. Then play that media item using player2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[player2 play];

Comment: If you want shuffled then you need to query to your array to fetch the media item at random position else get the media item by just increasing the array index.

Comment: hey i hav array of media item how can i add into whole array to url?

Comment: You cant load whole array to URL, you need to fetch each media item randomly from array and take its URL property.

Comment: thnx sir...nw i have loaded but problem arise-the play button not go to next row  when next song is play..help

Comment: That u need to handle,may be you can have some reference to currently playing item and in the tableview show the play button for that specific row.